# How to get gcc -O1 optimization without specifying -O1

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction

I know that -O1 automatically turns on certain flags.  These flags can be turned on manually though.  If I don't specify -O1, it should still be possible to get -O1 optimization by specifying all the flags that -O1 turns on.

I tried

```
-fthread-jumps -fcprop-registers -fguess-branch-probability
```

but it still does not do -O1 optimization.  I can tell when I use gprof because the performance is not as good.

Which flags do I turn on to get -O1 optimization?

Comment: Which flags do I turn on to get -O1 optimization? You turn on -O1.  Manually turning on each flag is a waste of your time and is error prone.  Just use the shortcut the GCC guys gave you instead of doing things the hard way!!!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778698/.

Comment: None of the answers here really state things clearly: It's not just that you can't simulate *full* `-O1`, it's that without using some `-O` option (or a pragma), optimization is still disabled and most of the `-f` options will do nothing, and you get a "debug" build where every C variable actually has an address in asm (and not keeping things in registers between statements.) 
 Duplicate of [Selecting gcc optimisation flags equivalent to -O1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769173) where Jonathan Wakely explains this clearly and links the GCC FAQ.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to find out:

```
gcc -O1 -c -Q -v dummy.c
```

(where dummy.c is your filename.) This causes gcc to spew the flags used to the command line.

**Edit:** Please see [kastauyra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778655/how-to-get-gcc-o1-optimization-without-specifying-o1/1782219#1782219) on this. It appears you cannot simulate full `-O1` optimization with `-f` flags alone.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, that's impossible. There are a lot of individual optimization flags turned on by -O1, true, however a lot of code in GCC checks global optimization flag value and performs optimizations not specified by any of -f.. options.

Comment: hmm that's news to me.. can quote doc?

Comment: The doc does not say that (probably a patch to change this would be accepted). But this can be seen from the source code (check for number of places if (optimize > 0) ... which do not check individual flags), also this has been asked on GCC mailing lists: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-02/msg00389.html

Comment: "Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag. Only optimizations that have a flag are listed in this section.

Most optimizations are only enabled if an -O level is set on the command line. Otherwise they are disabled, even if individual optimization flags are specified. " from: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

```
-O
-O1
Optimize. Optimizing compilation takes somewhat more time, and a lot more memory for a large function. 

With -O, the compiler tries to reduce code size and execution time, without performing any optimizations that take a great deal of compilation time. 

-O turns on the following optimization flags: 
          -fauto-inc-dec 
          -fcprop-registers 
          -fdce 
          -fdefer-pop 
          -fdelayed-branch 
          -fdse 
          -fguess-branch-probability 
          -fif-conversion2 
          -fif-conversion 
          -fipa-pure-const 
          -fipa-reference 
          -fmerge-constants
          -fsplit-wide-types 
          -ftree-builtin-call-dce 
          -ftree-ccp 
          -ftree-ch 
          -ftree-copyrename 
          -ftree-dce 
          -ftree-dominator-opts 
          -ftree-dse 
          -ftree-forwprop 
          -ftree-fre 
          -ftree-phiprop 
          -ftree-sra 
          -ftree-pta 
          -ftree-ter 
          -funit-at-a-time
```

Comment: There are other internal flags that cannot be "turned on" to simulate a full `-O1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to use this pragma (it requires GCC >= 4.4) :

```
#pragma GCC optimize opt_list
void f()
```

This pragma allow you to turn on and off specific optimizations for given function. opt_list is list of -f* options without -f.

There is also function attribute to change optimization level:

```
int f() __attribute__((optimize(1)));
```

You also can change global optimization level  (apply to all subsequent functions):

```
#pragma GCC optimize 1
#pragma GCC optimize 0
```

You also can use (apply to all subsequent functions):

```
#pragma GCC optimization_level n
```

and for Intel C compiler ([doc](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/cpp/win/cref_cls/common/cppref_pragma_optimization_level.htm); applied only for next function)

```
#pragma intel optimization_level n
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your version of `gcc`. See the [`gcc` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

On my machine, `-O` (which is `-O1`) turns on the following optimizations:

```
   -fauto-inc-dec -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop -fdelayed-branch
   -fdse -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion2 -fif-conversion
   -finline-small-functions -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference
   -fmerge-constants -fsplit-wide-types -ftree-builtin-call-dce
   -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-copyrename -ftree-dce
   -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-fre -ftree-sra -ftree-ter
   -funit-at-a-time

   -O also turns on -fomit-frame-pointer on machines where doing so
   does not interfere with debugging.
```