# How to turn off specific optimization flags in gcc

Tags: optimization, gcc, compiler-construction

I want to compile with optimization -O1, but there is a certain flag that it turns on that I do not want to use.  How do I turn it off?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778655/.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is usually an equivalent 'no' flag. For example, `fstrict-aliasing` can be turned off by `fno-strict-aliasing`. Check the gcc docs for more flags.

Comment: What about `avx512` optimization flag?