# Apply optimization flags to see how they affect output?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, compiler-optimization

I plan to do something like this for clang too. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778655/how-to-get-gcc-o1-optimization-without-specifying-o1/1778662#1778662) existing how to reproduce O1 with flags (which you can't do) but my goal is to apply a few optimizations to see the results, I don't need O1. Anyway...

I found this list of optimizations at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

I have basic source. I'm trying to get enough working that the results will be a single move (`mov rax, 1; ret`).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    return b;
}
```

I ran gcc with the below but the results look similar/same as a debug build. The output uses memory instead of mov 1 and return. How do I get gcc to apply these optimizations?

> gcc -c main.c -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop -fdse -fforward-propagate -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-modref -fipa-profile -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fipa-reference-addressable -fmerge-constants -fmove-loop-invariants -fmove-loop-stores -fomit-frame-pointer -freorder-blocks -fshrink-wrap -fshrink-wrap-separate -fsplit-wide-types -fssa-backprop -fssa-phiopt -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-ter -funit-at-a-time -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop -fdse -fforward-propagate -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-modref -fipa-profile -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fipa-reference-addressable -fmerge-constants -fmove-loop-invariants -fmove-loop-stores -fomit-frame-pointer -freorder-blocks -fshrink-wrap -fshrink-wrap-separate -fsplit-wide-types -fssa-backprop -fssa-phiopt -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-ter -funit-at-a-time -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop -fdse -fforward-propagate -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-modref -fipa-profile -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fipa-reference-addressable -fmerge-constants -fmove-loop-invariants -fmove-loop-stores -fomit-frame-pointer -freorder-blocks -fshrink-wrap -fshrink-wrap-separate -fsplit-wide-types -fssa-backprop -fssa-phiopt -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-ter -funit-at-a-time -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop -fdse -fforward-propagate -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-modref -fipa-profile -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fipa-reference-addressable -fmerge-constants -fmove-loop-invariants -fmove-loop-stores -fomit-frame-pointer -freorder-blocks -fshrink-wrap -fshrink-wrap-separate -fsplit-wide-types -fssa-backprop -fssa-phiopt -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-ter -funit-at-a-time

> objdump -D -M intel main.o > main.asm

---

I tried the below and it doesn't deoptimize the mov 1. So I don't see a way to exam a specific flag

> gcc -Og -c main.c  -fno-auto-inc-dec -fno-branch-count-reg -fno-combine-stack-adjustments -fno-compare-elim -fno-cprop-registers -fno-dce -fno-defer-pop -fno-dse -fno-forward-propagate -fno-guess-branch-probability -fno-if-conversion -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fno-ipa-modref -fno-ipa-profile -fno-ipa-pure-const -fno-ipa-reference -fno-ipa-reference-addressable -fno-merge-constants -fno-move-loop-invariants -fno-move-loop-stores -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-shrink-wrap -fno-shrink-wrap-separate -fno-split-wide-types -fno-ssa-backprop -fno-ssa-phiopt -fno-tree-bit-ccp -fno-tree-ccp -fno-tree-ch -fno-tree-coalesce-vars -fno-tree-copy-prop -fno-tree-dce -fno-tree-dominator-opts -fno-tree-dse -fno-tree-forwprop -fno-tree-fre -fno-tree-phiprop -fno-tree-pta -fno-tree-scev-cprop -fno-tree-sink -fno-tree-slsr -fno-tree-sra -fno-tree-ter -fno-unit-at-a-time -fno-auto-inc-dec -fno-branch-count-reg -fno-combine-stack-adjustments -fno-compare-elim -fno-cprop-registers -fno-dce -fno-defer-pop -fno-dse -fno-forward-propagate -fno-guess-branch-probability -fno-if-conversion -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fno-ipa-modref -fno-ipa-profile -fno-ipa-pure-const -fno-ipa-reference -fno-ipa-reference-addressable -fno-merge-constants -fno-move-loop-invariants -fno-move-loop-stores -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-shrink-wrap -fno-shrink-wrap-separate -fno-split-wide-types -fno-ssa-backprop -fno-ssa-phiopt -fno-tree-bit-ccp -fno-tree-ccp -fno-tree-ch -fno-tree-coalesce-vars -fno-tree-copy-prop -fno-tree-dce -fno-tree-dominator-opts -fno-tree-dse -fno-tree-forwprop -fno-tree-fre -fno-tree-phiprop -fno-tree-pta -fno-tree-scev-cprop -fno-tree-sink -fno-tree-slsr -fno-tree-sra -fno-tree-ter -fno-unit-at-a-time -fno-auto-inc-dec -fno-branch-count-reg -fno-combine-stack-adjustments -fno-compare-elim -fno-cprop-registers -fno-dce -fno-defer-pop -fno-dse -fno-forward-propagate -fno-guess-branch-probability -fno-if-conversion -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fno-ipa-modref -fno-ipa-profile -fno-ipa-pure-const -fno-ipa-reference -fno-ipa-reference-addressable -fno-merge-constants -fno-move-loop-invariants -fno-move-loop-stores -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-shrink-wrap -fno-shrink-wrap-separate -fno-split-wide-types -fno-ssa-backprop -fno-ssa-phiopt -fno-tree-bit-ccp -fno-tree-ccp -fno-tree-ch -fno-tree-coalesce-vars -fno-tree-copy-prop -fno-tree-dce -fno-tree-dominator-opts -fno-tree-dse -fno-tree-forwprop -fno-tree-fre -fno-tree-phiprop -fno-tree-pta -fno-tree-scev-cprop -fno-tree-sink -fno-tree-slsr -fno-tree-sra -fno-tree-ter -fno-unit-at-a-time -fno-auto-inc-dec -fno-branch-count-reg -fno-combine-stack-adjustments -fno-compare-elim -fno-cprop-registers -fno-dce -fno-defer-pop -fno-dse -fno-forward-propagate -fno-guess-branch-probability -fno-if-conversion -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fno-ipa-modref -fno-ipa-profile -fno-ipa-pure-const -fno-ipa-reference -fno-ipa-reference-addressable -fno-merge-constants -fno-move-loop-invariants -fno-move-loop-stores -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-reorder-blocks -fno-shrink-wrap -fno-shrink-wrap-separate -fno-split-wide-types -fno-ssa-backprop -fno-ssa-phiopt -fno-tree-bit-ccp -fno-tree-ccp -fno-tree-ch -fno-tree-coalesce-vars -fno-tree-copy-prop -fno-tree-dce -fno-tree-dominator-opts -fno-tree-dse -fno-tree-forwprop -fno-tree-fre -fno-tree-phiprop -fno-tree-pta -fno-tree-scev-cprop -fno-tree-sink -fno-tree-slsr -fno-tree-sra -fno-tree-ter -fno-unit-at-a-time

Comment: You actually do need *some* `-O` option, otherwise basically none of the `-f` options will do anything, and GCC will still be applying the `-O0` behaviour of making sure every C variable has an address in memory, and supporting consistent debugging, etc.  The other answers in the question you linked only hint at that; [Selecting gcc optimisation flags equivalent to -O1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48746895) says so explicitly.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh. So `-O0` didn't work but `-Og` did. I didn't think there was a difference. Although looking closely it appears that applies a bunch of optimizations so I guess I need to use `no-` a lot. I guess this is workable. TY

Comment: There are some optimization passes that don't have a `-f` option associated, but yes, `-Og` with a bunch of `-fno-` options is the least amount of optimization you can have other than a `-O0` debug build.

Comment: @PeterCordes It seems like it doesn't work. I'll edit the question

Comment: *and it doesn't deoptimize the mov 1.*  I didn't expect that it would.  `-O0` is special in terms of giving every variable an address in asm, unlike with optimization enabled. That's one of the things that doesn't have a `-f` option. (See also *[Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)* for more background on why that matters for consistent debugging, e.g. being able to `jump` to different lines within a function in GDB.)

Comment: None of the `-f` options are relevant to your case since there's nothing else to optimize.  If the function returned 0, you could see the difference `-fpeephole2` makes, using xor to zero a register.