# How to find out which specific optimization affects my code significantly using gcc

Tags: optimization, gcc

I used to think that I can mimic `-O1` in gcc by specifying `-fauto-inc-dec` and all the rest mentioned in [optimization options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for level one optimization. However, I was wrong because of one answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778655/how-to-get-gcc-o1-optimization-without-specifying-o1).

Let's say `-O1` indeed introduces significant impact on the code, then how can I find which optimization methods account for the difference?

EDIT:

I have used `gcc -c -Q -O1 --help=optimizers`, suggested in the answer to find out all the optimizer used in `-O1`, and use them using `-foptimizer` syntax. However, no significant difference is observed. Some optimizations don't have corresponding `-foptimizer` syntax, as mention in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778655/how-to-get-gcc-o1-optimization-without-specifying-o1), and I guess the hidden ones are making huge difference in this case. How can I find them out?

Comment: In your place I didn't use the  -O?  options, but played a little with turning on/off the different optimisation options independently.

Comment: In general you cannot. Look at [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC); see also `-fdump-tree-all`  and `-fdump-all-passes` options of `gcc`; perhaps consider using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

Comment: @PeterHorvath See revised question, how to find out the optimizations that don't have `-foptimizer` equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

You can diff:

```
gcc -c -Q -O1 --help=optimizers
```

and

```
gcc -c -Q -O0 --help=optimizers
```

This `gcc` command will display the list of enabled and disabled optimizer options for both `-O0` and `-O1`.

Then you can individually enable or disable specific optimizer options to see which one affects your program the most.

Comment: I could find out all the optimizers used in `-O1` using your method. However, when I specify them using `-fopitimizer` syntax, they don't improve the performance, which probably could be explained by this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778655/how-to-get-gcc-o1-optimization-without-specifying-o1), mentioned in the original question as well.