# How to check out gcc optimization options?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to figure out critical optimization options. First, compile a program with

```
gcc source.c -o test -O3 -Q -v
```

-Q -v lists the enabled flags (-faggressive-loop-optimizations -falign-labels -fasynchronous-unwind-tables etc.). Then if to provide these flags directly to gcc instead of -O3, the performance of the resulting program is if optimization was disabled.

gcc documentation states that

> Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag

Could this be the matter or I've missed smth else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, most likely you didn't miss anything. This was explained in this post

[How to get gcc -O1 optimization without specifying -O1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778655/how-to-get-gcc-o1-optimization-without-specifying-o1/1782219#1782219)

There are internal flags that could not be controlled by user but which are activated by global optimization flags like -O1, -O2, -O3, -Os or -Ofast.

You may try to "cheat" by first specifying -O1 and than adding your flags. But still there is no guarantee you will get same effect as doing -O3 in first place.

Short version - just don't do it. Use global switches and turn on/off single flags as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.
I was benchmarking matrix multiplication on Linux and Windows and realized that under certain circumstances Linux was quicker for about 5 times.
That's somehow related to arrays structure configuration, maybe some lucky cache alignment, however a curios fact.